# Absolute positioned element moves while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

As you can see in the image, i have a search dropdown that shouldnt be moving and should stay at the same position with search input.[image]

```
    <div>
      <div className="flex select-none m-2 items-center border-[#0b0c0f] rounded-md bg-[#1b1f2a] ">
        <input
          ref={searchInputRef}
          onClick={handleInputClick}
          onChange={(e) => {
            searchTokens(e.target.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Search for a token..."
          type="text"
          className="flex  form-control w-full  bg-[#1b1f2a] border-[#33353b] m-[0.2rem] rounded-l-md border-r-[0.1px]  p-2 !outline-none "
        />
        <div className="m-[0.10rem]"></div>
        <svg
          width="25px"
          height="25px"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          stroke="#999999"
          className="mr-2 "
        >
          <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="0" />

          <g
            id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
          />

          <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
            {" "}
            <path
              d="M15.7955 15.8111L21 21M18 10.5C18 14.6421 14.6421 18 10.5 18C6.35786 18 3 14.6421 3 10.5C3 6.35786 6.35786 3 10.5 3C14.6421 3 18 6.35786 18 10.5Z"
              stroke="#999999"
              strokeWidth="2"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
            />{" "}
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      {isInputClicked && (
        <div
          className={`overflow-y-auto custom-scrollbar absolute h-[250px] bg-[#12151D] border-[0.01px] border-[#33353b] w-[32.3vh] p-2`}
        >
          {foundTokens === null
            ? null
            : foundTokens.map((data) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    key={Date.now() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10043972894)}
                    className="p-2 cursor-pointer"
                  >
                    <div className="text-white">
                      {data.token_name} ({data.token_symbol})
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

I have tried the flex position but it stays the same.

Any recommendations?

I expect the search dropdown to be in the same position as search input and shoud not be affected by scrolling.

Comment: Can you create a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: Hey, i dont know how could i implement tailwind in codesandbox. I added the full search component code in the post,

Comment: You can [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/sandboxes/cli-api) any project into codesandbox. Make sure you remove whatever you don't want to share, though. The free version of codesandbox is public domain. Take your time.

Comment: There's a difference between `position: absolute` and `position: fixed`.

Comment: Did you add `position: relative;` to parent div of search box?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that className `relative` is missing in the first line of your example code.

Please note that when you are using `position: absolute` in a element, it will look up to the DOM tree to find the first element with `position` property set. In your case, it is probably `position: relative` for the search dropdown wrapper.